# Injecting React providers around page with Chrome Extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that injects some React components into a page. Some of these components need to be wrapped by providers to work properly (for example I am using `React Query` and `Chakra UI`). I'm currently doing that by wrapping each component with my providers when injecting them into the page, but I have a feeling that is not ideal:

```
export async function renderComponent(element: HTMLElement) {
  appendComponent(
    <Providers>
      <Component />
    </Providers>,
    element,
    "id",
  );
}
```

Is there a way to wrap the entire page with my providers so all injected components will have access to them without needing to wrap them individually? I've tried doing something with a content script, but am not sure how to wrap it around the entire page, nor if that would even work.

Comment: You can put your UI inside a special `web_accessible_resources` iframe of your extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm injecting multiple components into each page (and specific elements that already exist on the page) and I'm not really getting why this would help with my problem

Comment: @wOxxOm Do you think it can be done using portals or do you really think it can be done using `web_accessible_resources`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I actually think it's better to wrap the injected components with their own providers, this way you have less interactions with the page. And it sounds the providers you have hold no actual state, so there is no harm in doing so.
   Unfortunately, @vwos is right and the `ChakraProvider` does have an overhead
2. If the components you inject into the page are separate react roots (rendered with `ReactDOM.render`) you can't wrap them all with one provider
3. if the app you are injecting your components into is in react, and you have control over its code you can pass it the providers as props.
   but then the injected components need to be added to the existing app tree as well.. sounds like a mess
4. you can inject a single app (root component) of your own and render the injected components in portals - [here](https://github.com/alissaVrk/react-content-script) is a very simple example, injecting in each div a counter. Inspired by [this post](https://medium.com/@yosevu/how-to-inject-a-react-app-into-a-chrome-extension-as-a-content-script-3a038f611067).
   clone the repo, install local extension and try in google.com

Comment: 1. the problem with this is that the `ChakraProvider` has a noticeable impact on how quickly my injected components render 3. I don't have control over the page 4. I don't know understand how that would work with a Chrome extension and injecting components into specific HTML elements - an example would be great

Comment: 4. unfortunately I don't have experience with chrome extensions, but the same way you inject the components now. 1. are you sure that the number of providers matter? do an experiment, compare adding a single component with a single provider to adding the same component with multiple providers, connected to the same theme

Comment: 1. you can inject your App into the body, anywhere. and to portal the components into any html element

Comment: I did the experiment before posting and yes, the more `ChakraProvider`s rendered, the slower it becomes for my injected components to render.

I have never used portals before and I am simply not understanding how I can render my app with a Chrome extension and then portal the components into the page's DOM.

Comment: added an example, good luck :)

Comment: I think this is on the right track! Unfortunately because it is not in an iframe it results in the styles leaking (especially when using a `ChakraProvder`). If you render the app to an iframe, then you can't access the page's document (and thus query the divs), so I'm not sure what to do about that.

Comment: not familiar with chakra.. but maybe you can prefix its classes so styles won't leak. I don't understand what you are trying to do.. if you are injecting multiple iframes, each one will need all the css

Comment: I managed to figure it out thanks to you! :) Basically all I needed to change from your example was the css root of the provider and to also add something that keeps checking the document until the element I want to inject into exists.